# How can I return all columns in a table which contains only data with four characters or less?

Tags: mysql

I'm mapping data from a MySQL table and have a table that has over 50 columns and over 100,000 rows, and I need to map a column that **has data in it which has 4 characters or less**.

How can I get a list of all columns in the table which have data that contains only four characters or less? In my case, all columns are varchar(255).

Comment: My first suggestion was http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3573/1, but after reading your question again, it's not that simple ;-)

Comment: Sorry, my original question was unclear, I edited it above.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_NAME

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE TABLE_NAME = <table>
AND CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) <= 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean the *names* of the columns, but the *data* in the columns themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the columns whose name has 4 or less characters:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(Field) < 5
```

in above sql you just have to replace `table` with your table's name, `Field` is a literal you must keep it that way.

**UPDATE:**
If you want column contents with 4 or less characters, then you can like this:

```
select * from table where CHAR_LENGTH(column_name) < 5
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful in itself, but I don't mean the *names* of the columns, but the *data* in the columns themselves, e.g. the target source has a column that is expecting codes with four characters or less and I want map this as intelligently as I can by finding columns whose data meet this criteria.

Comment: That's nearer a solution, but somehow I need to get all columns from the table, check all the data in each column, and return the column name only if all the data satisfies the criteria that it is 4 characters or less.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a dynamic query using information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, then execute that. Untested, but something like:

```
SET @s = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(X) AS FOUR_CHAR_COLS, ID FROM (' + 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`' + COLUMN_NAME + 
        '`) <= 4 THEN ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' ELSE NULL END AS X, ID FROM MyTableName' 
          SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName') + 
    ') XX GROUP BY ID';

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This should list all columns in each row that have 4 characters or less.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via stored procedure.

1. Select all column names, which are of importance from table and store into temporary table;
2. Iterate with WHILE or REPEAT loop through them and perform SELECT LENGTH(column_name) FROM table.